# How can I call onchange function in checkboxes using a user array and axio get in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to get a user array in checkboxes this user array is having its elements from JSON placeholder. I want to display these values in checkboxes with onchange property, but somehow it displays nothing. Here is what I have done so far.

Here I have initialized the state and am having the value in `e` in handle click but it didn't appear on check box one suggestion I got was to create separate on change handlers for every element but how can I get them separately in on change. I have initialized state as { users: [] }

```
    componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then (res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({
          users: res.data
        })
      })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
      e.target.value;
      console.log(e)
      debugger
    }


          <div className="multiselect">
        <div className="selectBox">
          <select>
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div className="overSelect" ></div>
        </div>

        <div id="checkboxes">
          <label htmlFor ="one">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.users} id="one" onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange("users", e)} /></label>

        </div>
      </div>
        </Fragment>
```

Comment: Do you want to generate checkboxes dynamically based on the API response?

Comment: You are calling `handleChange` with 2 args: `this.props.handleChange("users", e)`.  But in `handleChange` you are taking only one.

Comment: First you have to add new property in your data with selected users and other is source with users so you can bind users and checked with selected users

Comment: i want to call dynamic checkboxes and please elaborate your answer for me

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer checkboxes?  Can you use `react-select`?  https://react-select.com/home

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.  In your collection of users, you need to find the one being toggled, toggle the `isSelected` key, then set the state.  The `checked` key looks for `user.isSelected` in your `render` call; it doesn't need to be defined at first as `undefined` will evaluate to false.

```
class App1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: []
        };
    }

    handleChange(user) {
        // get the user id
        const userId = user.id;

        // check the state, if a user is selected, toggle it
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            users: prevState.users.map(usr => {
                usr.id === userId
                    ? { ...usr, isSelected: !usr.isSelected }
                    : usr;
            })
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {Array.isArray(users) &&
                    users.length &&
                    users.map((u, idx) => {
                        <div key={`${idx}-${u.id}`}>
                            <label htmlFor={`${idx}-${u.id}`}>{u.name}</label>
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={u.isSelected}
                                onChange={() => this.handleChange(u)}
                            />
                        </div>;
                    })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```